# How to validate sub-sub classes of ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, activerecord

I want to validate some attributes before saving them to a database in ROR.

My code looks like this:

```
class AbstractClass < ActiveRecord::Base
 validate :field_name, :numericality => { :only_integer => true }
 self.abstract_class = true
end

class OtherAbstractClass < AbstractClass
  validate :other_field, :numericality => { :only_integer => true }
  self.abstract_class = true
end

class ConcreteClass < OtherAbstractClass
  validate :third_field, :numericality => { :only_integer => true }
end
```

My problem is that only the direct ancestor of ActiveRecord (field_name) validation are checked... and an instance of ConcreteClass does not even have a validate? method when I try to call them manually, and my objects are saved with only a partial validation.

Is there any way to call validation methods of ALL my subclasses of ActiveRecord ?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of `validate` is wrong, there should be no semicolon after it.

```
class ConcreteClass < OtherAbstractClass
   validate :field_name, :numericality => { :only_integer => true }
   validate :other_field, :numericality => { :only_integer => true }
   validate :third_field, :numericality => { :only_integer => true }

   # other code
end
```

Comment: The problem is that only   
validate :field_name, :numericality => { :only_integer => true }
Is called. I tried to move all validator in the sub class (ConcreteClass) but none was called..

Comment: @Antzi, I see. Your syntax in question is wrong, I just blindly copied them. The semicolon should not follow `validate` but before the symbol. I've revised it in my answer.

Comment: Why wouldn't superclass code be called? I'm not saying `validate` in particular will work, can't check at the moment--but it's normal code in a class declaration and there's no reason it wouldn't be called.

Comment: @BillyChan, I edited the code, I made a mistake by writing `validate: field_name` instead of `validate :field_name`, Thanks.

Comment: @DaveNewton, my bad to draw conclusion without too much thinking and verification. My previous claim is wrong. Sorry for the confuse.

Answer (score 0):

It's `validates :<some field>, ...` (plural) not `validate` (singular). `validate :<some method>` (singular) is used to call [custom validation methods](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods).